# Design reason behind setupUi()

Tags: c++, qt, raii

I'd like to know why, in your opinion, **Qt** engineers decided to put the `setupUi()` method in every generated form.

(for those who do not know how Qt works: `setupUi()` is a method which allocates in dynamic memory every button, texbox, widget which is inside the form. Every element's reference is stored inside a pointer member variable which is not even initialized to `nullptr` and it is placed under a `public:` access modifier, so that also looks like a somewhat dangerous situation until you actually call `setupUi()`)

In my newby opinion, that totally violates **RAII** principle, because that means any Ui_Whatever class is actually not constructed by its constructor call: constructor just allocates the class itself, but it is unusable till we call `Ui_Whatever::setupUi()`.

Which could be the design reason behind the choose of having:

- an empty compiler-generated default-constructor
- a method which do the real construction

(I'm asking 'cause I can't figure out myself any valid reason at all)

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Legacy reasons probably.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I agree, that it totally violates RAII principles. But I found a fairly easy workaround for that:

```
template<typename UiClass> class QtRaiiWrapper : public UiClass
{
public:
    QtRaiiWrapper(QMainWindow *MainWindow)
    {
        setupUi(MainWindow);
    }
};

...

#include "ui_Main.h"

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT
    ...
private:
    // Ui_MainWindow m_Ui; // no RAII
    QtRaiiWrapper<Ui_MainWindow> m_Ui; // RAII
};
```

(It might need some improvements, but this is the basic idea and works for me pretty well.)

Some more discussion on the topic:

Qt's choice of implementing the initialization via setupUi does not only lack RAII for this component, it can also make RAII impossible for other parts of your program, which is double bad. In my case, another object used the value of an GUI-Element for initialization (this way I could define the initial value in QtDesigner, rather than using a fake value there and overwriting it upon startup), but could not use RAII for that, because the GUI would only be initialized inside the body of the constructor of my MainWindow.

Therefore I disagree with Kuba Ober, you have not full control of when exactly you want the GUI to be initialized, as you can only do it inside the constructor body and not the initialization list (and following RAII, the initialization list is the place where perhaps most of all the initialization should happen). But luckily, C++ is awesome and we can write a workaround for that (as posted above). I also think this is far better than changing the way `uic` because as soon as other people try to compile your Code they will see a big surprise.

Comment: I'll take your answer as "there is no valid reason for the setupUi() double fase construction".

Answer (score 2):

The Ui class is not really a full-blown C++ class, it's just a wrapper that is supposed to become an integral part of something else.

By relegating the initialization to the `setupUi` method, you have control over exactly when will the widgets be instantiated. You may need to execute some setup before that time, and it would be impossible to do if the Ui class's constructor was doing the instantiating.

The pointers in the Ui class are not owning pointers. You *never have to explicitly delete them*. All the object pointers within the Ui class point to `QObject` instances that are owned by other `QObject` instances. The root of the ownership tree is the widget you pass to `setupUi`.  The RAII is effectively delegated to the owning `QObject` instance; there's no reason to duplicate that in `setupUi`.

If you insist on having an initialized Ui object, you can modify the `uic` tool to nullptr-initialize the pointers in the constructor. It's a 5-10 line change that I leave to the reader's fancy :) It's a waste of CPU cycles, as far as I'm concerned, but perhaps it could be useful in a debug build.

Comment: ok for the deletion mechanism, but I really do not like the two-fase initialization mechanism: whatever setup I need to do before `setupUi`, I should be able to do that also after the call... since there is no way to pass other parameters to `setupUi`, it should not be involved anyway...

Comment: @nyarlathotep108 The beauty of Qt is that you can change `uic` to emit exactly the code that you want. It's not a big change - you simply move the parent widget parameter, and the setupui's body, to ui class's constructor. If it's worth doing for you, then go for it :) I personally too use a rather seriously tweaked version of Qt, with a few dozen patches. Qt comes with source for all of its tools - unlike most commercial development frameworks, where you may have library source, but no tooling source.

Comment: @Kuba_Oder thanks, that's interesting... could you link a guide about how doing that?

Comment: @nyarlathotep108 There's no guide. 1. Compile Qt for yourself. 2. Open up the `uic` project in Qt Creator, figure out where the code output happens, and tweak it. It's not very hard code to understand.

Answer (score 0):

The problem behind one or two-phased initialization of UI sub-object is that the code in *setupUi(this)* needs the dynamic type of the form (`this` parameter) to be the real static type (class) of the form. But during initialization of parent classes and members it is of static type of parent class, not the form itself.
So all virtual function calls and RTTI can work different when called in the initialization phase of form object construction.
After opening brace of constructor function the dynamic and static types of the object are always same.